# SCSS changes "hsl($hue, 26, 100)" to "white"

Tags: css, sass

Writing a `@for` loop to produce a set of classes of varying background colors. SASS code:

```
@for $i from 0 through 15 {
    $classslug: writ;
    $hue: $i * 35 % 256;

    .#{$classslug}#{$i} {
        background: hsl($hue, 26, 100);
    }
}
```

Expected result:

```
.writ0 {
  background: hsl(0, 26, 100);
}

.writ1 {
  background: hsl(35, 26, 100);
}

.writ2 {
  background: hsl(70, 26, 100);
}

// etc.
```

Actual result from compilation:

```
.writ0 {
  background: white;
}

.writ1 {
  background: white;
}

.writ2 {
  background: white;
}

// etc.
```

How do I get the code that I am expecting? Compiled by Web Essentials v5(?) in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Similar, but definitely not a duplicate. The referenced question asks why Sass changes the code. I specifically asked how to get the code that I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the lightness parameter (the third one) of `hsl()` to `100`. Use some value close to but less than 100.